# I would like to append the name of a bunch of files automatically.

Tags: file, batch-file, append, names

I would like to append the name of a bunch of files.  Windows 7.  My files all have this name format:  NNNNNNN_NNNNN.tif.  I would like them to be changed to 111_NNNNNNN_NNNNN.tif.  Can I do this with a bat file or a script?

Comment: Could you be more specific with how you would like the prefix to look? Do you want consecutive integers?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean rename files using an iterator then yes with powershell (may not need $() for forced interpretation):

```
Dir *.tif | ForEach-Object -begin { $i=111 } -process { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "$($i)_$($_).tif"; $i++ }
```

With Batch:

```
@echo off

set i=111

for %%f in (*.tif) do call :renamefiles "%%f"
goto done

:renamefiles
ren %i_%1%.tif
set /A i+=1

:done
```